# Performing 2D fast fourier transform in R

Tags: r, fft

I want to know how to perform 2D fft in R. I can see the function `fft` only but I want to do that in 2D. Is there a function available like `fft2` in matlab?

Comment: There is indeed. It's called `fft2`. Which vesion of Matlab do you have?

In any case, a 2D FFT is just one FFT in the x direction followed by another FFT in the y direction (or vice versa). You could simply do that (which is what `fft2`does internally).

Comment: @LuisMendo. I want that in R. In R, I could only find fft

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Anyway, there's always the solution of cascading two FFT's. That's what a 2D-FFT is, actually. @user34790.

Comment: I don't think `matlab` tag is appropriate here... is it?

Comment: You could check out the package `smoothie` which has a 2D fft function.

Comment: `? fft` says: "When z contains an array, `fft` computes and returns the multivariate (spatial) transform." - isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: This post seems to say that R's `fft` does the same thing as Matlab's `fft2`: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Is-R-s-fast-fourier-transform-function-different-from-quot-fft2-quot-in-Matlab-td864669.html

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out in the comments, `fft` can handle single or multi-dimensional input. From the docs:

> When z is a vector, the value computed and returned by fft is the
>   unnormalized univariate Fourier transform of the sequence of values in
>   z. When z contains an array, fft computes and returns the multivariate
>   (spatial) transform.

I think this documentation is confusing the terms (since an R array can have 1, 2, or more dimensions), but what they are trying to say is fairly clear.